# Checking and validating topology relationship between 2 feature class by concurrent users?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, topology

My requirement is to allow several users to edit the map and validate the topology relationship between 2 feature class. Michael mentioned in my previous questions that I can only validate a topology when all users stop editting (which does not tally to my requirement).

Besides using the topology tool, what else can I use to check the topology relationship between 2 feature class?

Comment: Which particular topology relationship? If you're only checking then copy the data, make a topology, validate, export errors then delete the copy.

Comment: Hi Michael, so happy to see you here. The relationship between 2 polyline feature class is "must be covered with". Several user may edit the layer at the same time. We intend to ask user to validate once save edits.

Comment: You can validate 'on screen' whilst editing http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm00000016000000 using the topology toolbar. Apart from that you could write a custom tool to check each vertex from one feature class to another and attach it to the OnSaveEdits event.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?  Although this may be present in your earlier unlinked Questions you make life much easier for potential answerers if your Question can standalone by editing it to include these core details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate on screen or by selecting an area using the [topology toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm00000016000000). Beware if two people are editing then if the screen area overlaps you may still have conflicts.

If that's not working for you it is possible to write a custom tool to check each vertex from one feature class to another and attach it to the [OnSaveEdits](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000m5000000) event.

Comment: Yes Michael, that is the point. It seems I cannot prevent 2 people editting with overlaped screen area.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am thinking about the possibility of asking user to check and correct the topology before save edits, will this solve the concurrent issue? thanks

Comment: It should, provided the areas don't overlap. Consideration should also be given to validate whole topology on occasion, but this can only be done by one user accessing the data at a time.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment, I still need to confirm with user of all possible scenarios.